# Websocket server on Android

Tags: android, websocket, server

I am trying to implement simple websocket server on Android device.
I would like to use https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket but connection fails after a long timeout. I see that it is more than two years old withou answers in issues etc. Do you have any suggestions or similar experience? Do you have any alternatives?

Thanks!

code:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ClientHandshake;
import org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer;





public class WebsocketServer extends WebSocketServer 
{

public WebsocketServer(InetSocketAddress address) {
    super(address);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onClose(WebSocket arg0, int arg1, String arg2, boolean arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onError(WebSocket arg0, Exception arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(arg1.getStackTrace());

}

@Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onOpen(WebSocket arg0, ClientHandshake arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("new connection to " + arg0.getRemoteSocketAddress());


}
}
```

main

```
    String ipAddress = "10.0.0.140"
    InetSocketAddress inetSockAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, 38301);
    WebsocketServer wsServer = new WebsocketServer(inetSockAddress);
    wsServer.run();
```

js client -  it works with another ws server in python:

```
    var ws;

    $("#connect").click(function(e)
    {

            var ip = $("#address").val();
            ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + ip);
            ws.onopen = function()
            {
                 alert("connected!");
            };

    });
```

Comment: The Java-WebSocket is for a server - what are you using as your client?

Comment: Please provide more details so that we can answer the question more accurately. For example a sample of the code you are using.

Comment: @MaxWorg I am using simple javascript client working with another websocket server written in python.

Comment: it would be easier to troubleshoot if we can see the JavaScript as well (to make sure it's added the correct port number, etc).  Does your printout onOpen get triggered?

Comment: @anstosa excuse me, updated!

Comment: @MaxWorg no it is not triggered.

Comment: try updating your javascript to include the port number of the Java WebSocket ("ws://"+ip+":"+"38301")

Comment: @MaxWorg thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found hidden answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638927/anyone-successful-in-implementing-a-websocket-server-for-android).

I changed:

`wsServer.run();`

to

`wsServer.start();`

and it works!